# python mask matrice for selecting a list of vertices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix of booleans, whose shape is (N,N), e.g.:

```
[[True False False True]
 [...]
 [True True True False]]
```

and a numpy array of vertices, whose shape is (N,3), e.g:

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
 [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
 [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
 [1.0, 1.1, 1.2]]
```

I would like to compute a matrix, with shape (N, varying), in which each row is a list of vertices selected with each line of the boolean matrix.
From the examples above:

```
[[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [1.0, 1.1, 1.2]]
 [...]
 [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.4, 0.5, 0.6],[0.7, 0.8, 0.9]]]
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach after extracting rows, columns from the mask -

```
r,c = np.where(mask)
start = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(r[1:] != r[:-1])+1]
stop = np.r_[start[1:], r.size]
data_rep = data[c]
out = [data_rep[start[i]:stop[i]] for i in range(len(start))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Divakar !!
I tried your solution and it works fine.

However, I also tried a solution with a loop:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    result.append(data[mask[i]])
```

and it's faster than doing:

```
result = extract_rows_using_mask(data, mask)
```

Weird isn't it ?

Comment: Hi Divakar, it works !! 
It is faster than my loop, and I can compute the 'out' array including functions (np.sum for example) directly.
You saved may day, thanks